# How does this make sense: *(void **)(&fptr) = dlsym(handle, "my_function");`

Tags: c

The code comes from this page: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html

Can you help me understand this?
It takes the address of the function pointer, casts it to void** and then dereferences it. I don't know why it has to work like this.

I appreciate your help! Until now, the only advice I have gotten was "read it from right to left" or something like "read it in cycles from right to left".

Comment: I cannot understand it either. I'd have used `fptr = (fptr_t)dlsym(...)`, where `fptr_t` is the actual type of `fptr`.

Comment: @vhallac: The author of the remarks/example in POSIX claims that the C standard requires your cast to generate a warning. However I can find no such requirement in the C standard. That's the reason they wrote it their way anyway, but see my answer as to why their solution is invalid.

Comment: @R.. I did (both your answer and their rationale). To be honest, I've never seen this as an issue until now. Thanks for your answer. I learned something new about C today. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The meaning of the code is:

1. Take the address of `fptr`. The type of this expression is pointer-to-pointer-to-function (of some specific type).
2. Cast that pointer expression to "pointer to pointer to void".
3. Dereference that pointer to access the object `fptr` as if it were an object of type `void *`.
4. Assign the result of the right to the lvalue obtained in step 3.

Unfortunately, whoever wrote this example in POSIX was on crack, because step 3 violates the aliasing rules of the C language and thus invokes undefined behavior. In particular, **real-world** compilers will optimize this code in ways that breaks the intended usage.

What the author of this example was *trying* to achieve was avoiding casting the right-hand side from *pointer to void* to *pointer to function*. This is based on a claim that the C standard requires this cast to generate a warning, but I have searched thoroughly for such a requirement and can find no such requirement.

If such a problem really does exist (the warning requirement), then the only way to silence the warning without invoking undefined behavior (like the bad example in the text of POSIX) is to do this:

```
void (*fptr)(); // or whatever function pointer type you want
void *temp = dlsym(handle, "my_function");
memcpy(&fptr, &temp, sizeof fptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns an a function pointer.  That code says hey take my function pointer variable give me the address of it. Cast it to `void **`.  Now deference the `void **` and set the value of the void * = to the pointer I got from the call.

Answer (score 0):

`*(void **)(&fptr) = dlsym(handle, “my_function”);`

To make this simpler,

`fptr` is a pointer.

`&fptr` is the address of that pointer.

you are typecasting it to a `pointer to a pointer to a void`

and then reference and assign the return value from function.